# Get the value of one .m file and use those values to plot in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

lets suppose i have a .m file which contains the following code

```
a=[1:0.01:10]
x=sin(2.*pi.*a)
plot(a,x)
check
```

where *check.m* is GUI file which takes the value **a** and **x** plot it in *axes1*.
Question1: Even the values of **a** and **x** are in workspace check still does not get those values. How can i give the values of **a** and **x** in ***OpeningFcn***?
Question2: How can i import the plot ***plot(a,x)*** to GUI axes1.

P.S: This is just a simple example. I have more than 5 plots of 10000s of data.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `copyobj` or  `copyaxes` to copy the axes into the GUI, it sounds like your workflow would be better the other way around though, create a GUI object with a handle, and a plot method which plots into the correct axes. This is currently too broad, so it's hard to suggest a real fix.

Comment: You can either: (a) modify `check.m` into a function so it takes `a` and `x` as input variables, or (b) use the familly of function `asignin/evalin` somewhere in your gui so it can access variables from the workspace, or (c) probably many opther ways to do it... I recommend you to try (a), if still unsuccessful, modify your question accordingly and ask for help showing which method you tried, the code with it, and describe what does not work as planned.

Comment: Try declaring the a and x variables as global. Search on internet how to assign and access global variables in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

make the 'a' and 'x' as global variables and call them in the check.m